# Get latest records per timestamp from large table - Index is not used

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-9.4

I have several staging tables where records are inserted/updated (not deleted) regularly.

Each table has a 'BEFORE UPDATE' trigger updating a timestamp column with the current timestamp.

There is a process running periodically fetching the latest records (delta) from each staging table based on a timestamp that is stored in a control table. This is done using a materialized view.

The control table is updated with the max(timestamp) found from the materialized views every time the above process runs

Control table:

```
id | staging_table_name | input_last_update_timestamp |
---+--------------------+-----------------------------+
 1 | stg_table1         | 2018-06-29 12:57:19         |
 2 | stg_table2         | 2018-06-29 13:52:19         |
```

**stg_table1**

```
id      | internal_timestamp  
--------+--------------------
6875303 | 2018-06-29 14:18:17 
6874765 | 2018-06-29 14:18:17 
6875095 | 2018-06-29 14:18:17 
6867996 | 2018-06-29 14:18:17 
6873723 | 2018-06-29 14:18:17 
6874594 | 2018-06-29 14:18:17 
6868561 | 2018-06-29 14:18:17 
6875292 | 2018-06-29 14:18:00 
6874595 | 2018-06-29 14:18:00 
6875300 | 2018-06-29 14:18:00
```

I have tried the following queries but non of them use the index i have on the 'internal_timestamp' column of the staging table

**Query1**:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.internal_timestamp
FROM 
    staging_scm.stg_table1 p,
    control_staging_scm.control_table o
WHERE 
    p.internal_timestamp > o.input_last_update_timestamp 
    AND o.id = 21
```

Query2

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.internal_timestamp
FROM 
    staging_scm.stg_table1 p
JOIN 
    control_staging_scm.control_table o ON p.internal_timestamp > o.input_last_update_timestamp
WHERE 
    o.id = 21
```

Query3

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.internal_timestamp
FROM 
    staging_scm.stg_table1 p
WHERE 
    p.internal_timestamp > (SELECT o.input_last_update_timestamp 
                            FROM control_staging_scm.control_table o 
                            WHERE o.id = 21)
```

Explain plans:

```
Query 1 and 2
Nested Loop  (cost=0.03..203273.39 rows=1539352 width=12) (actual time=2013.969..2058.475 rows=520 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (p.internal_timestamp > o.input_last_update_timestamp)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 4615088
  Buffers: shared hit=173254
  ->  Index Scan using control_table_pkey on control_table o  (cost=0.03..4.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = 21)
        Buffers: shared hit=2
  ->  Seq Scan on stg_table1 p  (cost=0.00..187106.17 rows=4618055 width=12) (actual time=0.003..419.628 rows=4615608 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=173252
Planning time: 0.110 ms
Execution time: 2058.533 ms

Query 3

Seq Scan on stg_table1 p  (cost=4.03..189419.23 rows=1539352 width=12) (actual time=2020.801..2054.617 rows=675 loops=1)
  Filter: (internal_timestamp > $0)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 4614988
  Buffers: shared hit=173254
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using control_table_pkey on control_table o  (cost=0.03..4.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = 21)
          Buffers: shared hit=2
Planning time: 0.155 ms
Execution time: 2054.694 ms
```

When I set enable_seqscan = OFF the index is used and the performance is orders of magnitude better

**Explain Plan (Seqscan OFF)**

```
    Nested Loop  (cost=41794.55..225088.07 rows=1539618 width=12) (actual time=0.100..0.557 rows=407 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=97
  ->  Index Scan using control_table_pkey on control_table o  (cost=0.03..4.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (id = 21)
        Buffers: shared hit=2
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on stg_table1 p  (cost=41794.52..220465.18 rows=1539618 width=12) (actual time=0.085..0.317 rows=407 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (internal_timestamp > o.input_last_update_timestamp)
        Heap Blocks: exact=90
        Buffers: shared hit=95
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stg_table1_internal_timestamp_idx  (cost=0.00..41717.54 rows=1539618 width=0) (actual time=0.070..0.070 rows=407 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (internal_timestamp > o.input_last_update_timestamp)
              Buffers: shared hit=5
Planning time: 0.131 ms
Execution time: 0.631 ms
```

No need to mention that i run Analyze on the staging table and i have set autovacuum/autoanalyze accordingly

So what will it take for the planner to use the index on 'internal_timestamp' on the staging table?

**UPDATE 1**

Before trying what @Laurenz suggested below, i was curious where a CTE or a scalar function would do the trick.

But unfortunately the optimizer whouldn't use the index in both solutions

CTE

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT o.input_last_update_timestamp 
    FROM control_staging_scm.control_table o 
    WHERE o.id = 21
)
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.internal_timestamp
FROM 
    staging_scm.stg_table1 p
WHERE 
    p.internal_timestamp > (SELECT x.input_last_update_timestamp FROM x)
```

SCALAR FUNCTION

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION control_staging_scm.last_update_timestamp(_table_id integer)
RETURNS timestamp without time zone
AS $function$

   SELECT o.input_last_update_timestamp FROM control_staging_scm.control_table o WHERE o.id = $1;

$function$ LANGUAGE 'sql';


SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.internal_timestamp
FROM 
    staging_scm.stg_table1 p
WHERE 
    p.internal_timestamp > (SELECT control_staging_scm.last_update_timestamp(21))
```

I was expecting/hoping that the value (timestamp) would be calculated and be available to the optimizer before the execution of the main query.

It would be nice if someone pointed out what is the internal pehaviour of the optimizer for the above cases!

Comment: The optimizer cannot know that the one row found in `control_table` will cause the condition to be selective enough to warrant using an index. I can't think of a good remedy right now. This is a crude hack, but adding a `LIMIT` clause would make a difference.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I cant grasp that the optimizer wouldn't evaluate a simple scenario as such as expected. Especially the 3rd query what is the difference from a simple subquery selecting ids from another table?
The optimizer wouldn't evaluate the subquery condition first and passing the result to the outter query in such cases?
I have put a LIMIT just to see if it would make any difference but still it prefers a sequencial scan.
I am curious if adding a reference of the control table id on the staging table would make any difference for the join condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimizer knows quite well that there will only be one matching row from `control_table`, but it cannot predict what value the `input_last_update_timestamp` column will have (that is only known at query execution time), so it has no good way of knowing how many result rows from `stg_table1` it should expect.

Lacking this knowledge, it falls back to estimating that one third of the rows will be selected, which is best done with a sequential scan.

You can improve that by splitting the query into two parts:

```
SELECT o.input_last_update_timestamp 
FROM control_staging_scm.control_table o 
WHERE o.id = 21;

SELECT p.id, p.internal_timestamp
FROM staging_scm.stg_table1 p
WHERE p.internal_timestamp > <result from first query>;
```

Then the actual value will be known when the second query is planned, ane PostgreSQL will choose the index scan if only a few rows match the condition.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

As suggested by @Laurenz i tried to separate the two queries and use the result of the 1st one as a parameter on the 2nd query.

I did it using 'plpgsql' function that returns a table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION control_staging_scm.update_stgtable1_delta_mat_view()
 RETURNS TABLE (
    trade_id int4
 ,  internal_timestamp timestamp
 )  
AS $function$

DECLARE 

last_update_timestamp_temp_var timestamp WITHOUT time ZONE;

BEGIN

    SELECT input_last_update_timestamp into last_update_timestamp_temp_var
    FROM control_staging_scm.control_table
    WHERE id=21;

    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT  p.trade_id AS tr_id,          
            p.internal_timestamp AS intr_timestamp,
    FROM staging_scm.stg_table1 p
    WHERE p.internal_timestamp > last_update_timestamp_temp_var;

END;
$function$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT * FROM  control_staging_scm.update_stgtable1_delta_mat_view()
```

**Explain Plan**

```
Function Scan on update_stgtable1_delta_mat_view  (cost=0.05..3.05 rows=1000 width=640) (actual time=0.828..0.847 rows=321 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.049 ms
Execution time: 0.888 ms
```

Finally the optimizer choose to use the index (see Seqscan OFF query plan on the question above). 
So we ended up with a ~2000x faster query not bad at all:)

Of course if you can suggest a better answer please feel free to do so!